# How to make website multi vendor without using the extension-opencart 2

Tags: php, opencart2.x

I am new to opencart.I want to make my website multi vendor.I see many extensions but i want to do with the coding not from the using plugins.please help me if anybody know about coding.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be done so many ways. In one of my project, it followed some rules.

- Create a vendor table to save vendor's basic data.
- add a vendor_id in store table to map with vendor table.
- Assign role for vendor user.
- analyze your requirements properly and add a column `store_id` in all tables where multi vendors data will be available.
- Update codes of your all modules based on your db schema changes.

Hope it may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

P.S. I m posting answer now because i found this question while google, and thought t will good for future OP, giving external link because OP asking for extension of code to convert their website into Multi seller platform.

While searching 2 days ago, i found List of modules which can help anyone to convert into Multi seller OpenCart website. Let me show you one Module which i like most here is 
List of features of [OpenCart Multi Vendor Module](https://blog.opencartextensions.in/top-5-free-opencart-extensions-modules-tmd/) and if anyone is looking to buy Multi vendor module for his or her website than please visit TMD [OpenCart Extensions](https://www.opencartextensions.in/multi-vendor-multi-seller-supplier-marketplace) Website they are giving out good service as well.